# Spring data and ElasticSearch, how do I search by an entire object?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have the following mapping

```
 "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "_class": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },

...

      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "username": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "userType": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },

...
```

My java object looks like this

```
class foo {
   String id,
   ...
   User user;
   ...
}

class User {
   String username;
   UserType userType; // this is enum
}
```

In my repository I am trying to find by

```
  public List<Foo> findByUser(User user);
```

This will not return anything, I double and triple checked the data and mapping and the user object that I am passing. All looks good, but I won't get any results.

If I write a query like so, it does work:

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
            {
                "term" : {
                "user.username" : {
                    "value" : "user1"
                }
                }
            },
            {
                "term" : {
                "user.userType" : {
                    "value" : "ACTIVE"
                }
                }
            }
            ]
        }        
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the OneToOne or OneToMany relationship related annotations.

Comment: tried with and without. Didn't work